# jQuery hide().slideDown() does not work when I have CSS animations enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to this.

I used jQuery to make three divs (buttons) slideDown at page load. Then I made them expand a little (downwards) when mouseover'd. This worked well in Safari but not in Firefox. So I changed around a few things.

Now I have CSS animations to make them expand on hover and a jQuery function to make them slideDown on load. But this slideDown doesn't seem to work properly.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="button_container">
        <a href = "../index.htm"><div class="header_button home_button">Back to Home</div></a>
        <a href = "../Projects/projects.htm"><div class="header_button projects_button">Projects</div></a>
        <a href = "../Resume/resume.htm"><div class="header_button resume_button" >Resume</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header_button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 130px;
    line-height: 130px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}

.header_button:hover {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    height: 140px;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}
```

Some of the stuff has been copy-pasted from all over Stack Overflow. But now I've got the hover-expand thing working.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header_button').hide().slideDown('slow');
});
```

[**Convenient jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/BaRd3/)

Comment: What is that CSS? Please re-check what you have pasted

Comment: @ShaunakD Yeah, I realized. I posted a fiddle that functions properly (esp. if viewed on a wide screen).

Comment: You have not ended document ready with `});`

Comment: Oh sorry about that. It has been ended properly in the actual code. I only posted the relevant snippet required to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BaRd3/8/)**

Check this code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header_button').parent().hide().slideDown('slow');
});
```

Though you hide `.header_button` it has parent `<a>` which is still visible.

Comment: Ooh thanks! This is perfect. Still, the shadow only appears after the slideDown has completed. Is there a way to fix this? It's not that big of a deal.

Comment: Ohh, that is because all elements slide down simultaneously, so unless all elements completely open, shadow wont appear.